# Deletar linhas que contém NA em um data frame

Tags: r, data.frame

Tenho um data frame e na quarta coluna há diversas células NA. Gostaria de saber como posso deletar todas as linhas que tenham NA. Utilizei esse comando mas eles continuam aparecendo
dataframe1

```r
r <- with(dataframe1, which(dataframe1[4]==NA, arr.ind=TRUE))
newd <- dataframe1[-r, ]
```

A estrutura dos meus dados é:

```r
dput(head(dataframe1, 10))

structure(list(Sigla = c("AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", "AC", 
"AC", "AC", "AC", "AC"), CÃ³digo = c(1200013L, 1200054L, 1200104L, 
1200138L, 1200179L, 1200203L, 1200252L, 1200302L, 1200328L, 1200336L
), MunicÃ.pio = c("AcrelÃ¢ndia", "Assis Brasil", "BrasilÃ©ia", 
"Bujari", "Capixaba", "Cruzeiro do Sul", "EpitaciolÃ¢ndia", "FeijÃ³", 
"JordÃ£o", "MÃ¢ncio Lima"), `numero de homicidios` = c(4L, NA, 
1L, NA, 1L, 1L, NA, 1L, NA, 1L), `media escolaridade` = c(3.268, 
3.72, 3.788, 2.816, 2.417, 4.108, 3.681, 1.948, 1.038, 3.537), 
    rendimento = c(1042.3834261349, 429.2221666106, 2243.2492197717, 
    786.6815828794, 603.835515482, 9363.3159742031, 1503.420009265, 
    1737.0793588989, 130.7838314018, 1040.2388777272), populacao = c(7935L, 
    3490L, 17013L, 5826L, 5206L, 67441L, 11028L, 26722L, 4454L, 
    11095L)), .Names = c("Sigla", "CÃ³digo", "MunicÃ.pio", "numero de homicidios", 
"media escolaridade", "rendimento", "populacao"), row.names = c(NA, 
10L), class = "data.frame")
```

Comment: Segue a estrutura do meu código usando dput(head(dataframe1, 1)):dput(head(dataframe1, 1))
structure(list(Sigla = "AC", CÃ³digo = 1200013L, MunicÃ.pio = "AcrelÃ¢ndia", 
    `numero de homicidios` = 4L, `media escolaridade` = 3.268, 
    rendimento = 1042.3834261349, populacao = 7935L), .Names = c("Sigla", 
"CÃ³digo", "MunicÃ.pio", "numero de homicidios", "media escolaridade", 
"rendimento", "populacao"), row.names = 1L, class = "data.frame")

Answer (score 11):

Há duas soluções. Se você quiser omitir todos os NA do data.frame, você pode usar a função `na.omit`.

Por exemplo, suponha um data.frame com duas colunas, em que há NA's nas duas.

```r
### Construindo um data.frame de exemplo ###
set.seed(1)
df <- data.frame(x=rnorm(100), y = rnorm(100))
df[sample(1:100,20),1] <- NA
df[sample(1:100,20),2] <- NA
```

O comando `na.omit` vai retirar todas as linhas que tenham pelo menos um NA:

```r
df2 <- na.omit(df)
```

Mas se você quiser omitir apenas as linhas que possuem NA em uma coluna específica, você pode usar a função `is.na` para fazer o subset do data.frame. A função `is.na` retorna `TRUE` se o valor for `NA`, deste modo você vai negar `!` o resultado no subset.

Por exemplo, o comando abaixo retira apenas as linhas que tem NA em `x`:

```r
df3 <- df[!is.na(df$x),]
```

Comment: Muito obrigada :)

Answer (score 4):

Outra opção é utilizar a função `complete.cases`

```
df2 <- df[complete.cases(df),]
```

A função `complete.cases` retorna um vetor lógico de TRUE e FALSE. Como utilizado no exemplo acima, são selecionados apenas os casos com todas as observações que não contenham nenhuma variável com NA.